# Design: Task-Asynchronous Pattern (TAP with await / async), vs threads with signalling vs other thread structures

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, async-await, unmanaged

Help with ideas for redesign of the below C# program would be greatly appreciated. I am trying to pick between implementing multithreading using 1) TAP, 2) course-grained threads that contain spinners that terminate when their bools are set to false, or 3) the same threads using signalling instead of these bools. I will explain the program below, to make the case clear.

**The Program**

The program is a game automation application in C# that I am developing as a fun way to learn the language and C# (5.0) features better. It has a UI that needs to remain responsive while the app runs.

When a particular tab in the UI is opened, the program fires up a new thread called "Scan" that, in a new method in another class, scans various memory locations and updates labels in the UI with these quickly changing values using the UI's SynchronizationContext. This goes on in a while(scanning) loop, for as long as scanning bool is true (usually the full life-duration of the program).

When the user clicks the Start button on this tab, the program fires up two new threads that does the following: Thread "Run" moves the character around following a particular path. Thread "Action" hits particular buttons and performs actions at the same time as the player runs the path. If a certain scenario occurs, the program should stop the running thread and the action thread temporarily, run a method, and when it finishes, go back to the running and action'ing.

When the user clicks the Stop button on this tab, the automation should halt and threads terminate.

**The Challenge**

I have already created a working version using continuous spinner loops in each thread that takes care of the various work. The spinners run using a while(myBool). For the three threads the bools are: scanning, running and actioning.

When I want to stop a thread I set the bool to false, and use a Thread.Join to wait for the thread to terminate gracefully before proceeding. The threads can, as mentioned, be stopped by the user clicking the Stop button, or automatically by the program as part of its functionality. In the latter case a thread is stopped, Joined, and then at a later stage restarted.

After having done a lot of reading and research on threading and the new async programming tools in C# 5.0, I have realized that the way I am currently doing it might be very clumsy and unprofessional. It creates lots of synchronization/thread-safety issues, and as the goal of all of this is to learn more about C# I wanted to get your take on whether I should change it to a fine-grained asynchrounous programming approach instead, using TAP with async and await as appropriate.

Does this sound like a case where Tasks with cancellation tokens could be useful? The threads are after all long-running operations, so I was concerned that using the thread pool (Task.Run) would cause bad hygiene in the thread pool (over-subscription). If async programming seems like a bad match here, what about using threads as I have done, but instead use signalling to start and stop the threads?

Any thoughts greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you considered using TPL DataStream or ReactiveExtensions? Both are designed for concurrent and/or asynchronous data pipelining.

Answer (score 0):

No. TPL was designed to run shorter tasks where the allocation of new threads all time would hurt perfomance. It got quite nice features like job queues and work stealing (a TPL thread can take jobs from another thread). It can of course have longer running task, but you wont get so many benefits from that. On the contrarary, you force TPL to allocate new threads.

However, the question is a bit general in the sense that we need more information about your actual implementation to know what you should use. For the Scan thread it's quite obvious that it should run in a single thread.

But for the others it's hard to know. Do they do work all the time or periodically? If they do work all the time you should keep them in seperate threads.

As for the thread syncronization there is another alternative. You could use a `ConcurrentQueue` to queue up everything that has to be drawn. In that way you do not need any synchronization. Just let the UI thread check the queue and draw anything in it, while the producers can continue to do their work.

In fact, in that way you can move anything not related to UI drawing to other threads. That should also improve the responsiveness in your application.

```
public void ActionRunnerThreadFunc()
{
    _drawQueue.Enqueue(new SpaceShipRenderer(x, y));
}

public void UIThreadFunc()
{
    IItemRender item;
    if (_drawQueue.TryDequeue(out item))
        item.Draw(drawContext);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer J. The app is not actually a game, but rather a tool that automates gameplay (so moves the character around and performs various tasks, without human interaction). I thought tasks seemed useful, as they can have a return type, as well as offers the possibility to attach continuations (either explicitly with an awaiter or implicitly through the `await` keyword). So I think you are right that the memory scanner should just simply run on a separate thread, and can use a ManualResetEvent.WaitOne instead of the scanner bool. (continued in next comment)

Comment: But for the two other threads: They do not run forever. Lets say what I want to do is chop trees. So one thread has the character run around in a set path. The other thread, which runs in parallel, is constantly clicking a button to look for trees. Once a tree is found, both these two threads should halt temporarily, and the method treeChopping should start. When the tree is done chopping, the player should get back to running the path looking for trees. It feels like three tasks would work well here right?

Comment: If the tree cutting completes within a second I would run it in a task. Otherwise I would keep it in a seperate thread.

Comment: But what about just using TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning, to avoid thread pool? What is the reason to not use tasks here u think?

Comment: " principle of least astonishment".

Comment: I see, but with regards to that principle, tree-chopping really feels like a task, no? Same with the task of looking for trees and the task of running a path until tree is found. Return type and cancellation tokens will come to great use no? Imagine, no bools to stop the spinner loops (just pass a cancellation token to the task), and the tree chopping task (as an example) can return a string which the continuation can respond to (with say a switch statement). I was once told that many old threading techniques (Join/Sleep etc) are obsolete now that we have Tasks-based Asynchrony. Might be wrong

Comment: -1 This answer seems to conflate and confuse several technologies. TAP != TPL != Task.Run != `ThreadPool.Enqueue`. The main benefit of using TAP is that TAP IS a rich API with a powerful framework (such as TPL) to back it up. TAP itself is just a bunch of (pseudo)interfaces, for which there are many implementations. The MAIN benefit for using TAP is that you can move between implementations with a common set of methods (polymorphism).

Comment: Your answer read like you are explaining wss websockets to someone who asked about ethernet.

Comment: If you google "TAP C#" the first MSDN article have the title "Task-based Asynchronous Programming" while the first paragraph talks about TPL. From the scope of this question that association is just fine as the OP asks if he should use explicit threads or TAP instead. My first paragraph tries to explain that using tasks for long lived tasks (without additional tasks within them) will effectively force the task scheduler to use more threads. In that sense long running CPU bound operations get no benefit from being wrapped in a task instead of an own thread.

Comment: I disagree with that *"The MAIN benefit for using TAP is that you can move between implementations with a common set of methods (polymorphism)."*. To state benefits you have to compare with something and APM is the other model in .NET. TAP gives you so much more compared to APM. My two main reasons to use TAP is that the code is much easier to maintain as tasks+scheduler removes a lot of plumbing. (or EAP as async is solved in the socket classes)