# TAP / TPL for Long-Running, Compute-Bound Operations: Bad Idea?

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, task-parallel-library

Title says it all: Is it a bad idea to use the task based asynchronous programming (TAP / TPL) for long-running compute-bound operations? I am concerned about thread pool hygiene (i.e. over-subscription when using Task.Run) etc., but feel there is strong benefits with TAP (tasks can return types and offer continuations either implicitly with `await` or explicitly). TAP also simplifies synchronization.

The following is a more detailed application example, though the general question still stands: [Design: Task-Asynchronous Pattern (TAP with await / async), vs threads with signalling vs other thread structures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26326207/design-task-asynchronous-pattern-tap-with-await-async-vs-threads-with-sign)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning` when creating the task to signal to the TPL that the operation is long running and shouldn't use the thread pool.

Comment: Thanks Servy. If you have time I would really appreciate it if you took a quick look at the post I linked to. I feel your suggested method here might be a better option than the current answer... After all, tree-chopping is a task..